# Python top 5 letter getter

Tags: python

I have a coding project and here is my code

```
from operator import itemgetter 
# 1. Get input
# 2. Split each letter and number
# 3. Find the 5 most frequent numbers
# 4. Find the letter or number and print the answers
countcount = 0

N = 5
# Overview code
input123 = str(input('Please enter your letters \n')).replace(" ", "")
test_list = str({i :input123.count(i) for i in set(input123)})

# Get Top N elements from Records 
# Using sorted() + itemgetter() 
res = sorted(test_list, key = itemgetter(0), reverse = True)[:N] 
  
# printing result 
print("The top N records are : " + str(res))
print(str(res))
```

As you can see, I want to enter a random string and get the top 5 letter/numbers. Right now if I enter qqqqqqwwwwweeeerrrtty, 2 of the answers would be `{` and `}` while the rest would be either q,w,e,r,t or y. Am I using `itemgetter` wrongly?

Comment: I do not understand the first answer `{ and }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another datatype that might be more suitable for counting e.g. characters is the Counter which has a built-in most_common method.

```py
from collections import Counter
_input = input("Please enter your letters: ").replace(" ", "")
counter = Counter(_input)
print(counter.most_common(5))
# Or the below row in case you only want the character and not the tuple with char + num of occurences.
# print([tup[0] for tup in counter.most_common(5))
```

Given the input `qqqqqqwwwwweeeerrrtty`you would get the output `['q','w','e','r','t']` or `[('q', 6), ('w', 5), ('e', 4), ('r', 3), ('t', 2)]`depending on which of the two print options you select in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

`itemgetter` is not the issue.
You shouldn't convert  `test_list` into a `str` (this is what introduces the `{}`); instead keep it as a dict. Then refer to [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value) to sort the dict as you wished.